# Largest Java Short (32767) plus 1 not turning negative?

Tags: java, binary, short, twos-complement

recently I learned about the two's compliment method of representing both positive and negative integers in the base two system. I then tried to see this in action using java with the following short code:

```
int a=2147483647;
System.out.println("a: "+a);
System.out.println("a+1: "+(a+1));
short b=32767;
System.out.println("b: "+b);
System.out.println("b+1: "+(b+1));
```

Which outputs:

> a: 2147483647
>
> a+1: -2147483648
>
> b: 32767
>
> b+1: 32768

Which confuses me because I would think that b+1, being represented in binary as 011111111111111, would turn into 1000000000000000, or in decimal, -32768. What's going on?

Comment: Doing `+ 1` automatically promotes it to `int`, so no overflow happens.

Comment: Try to  go one up in this way `short b=32767; b++;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although `b` is a short, the expression `(b + 1)` is an int. The right operand is an int, the left operand is promoted to an int, and the expression is the promoted type of the operands.

From the Java Language Specification, [5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

Note that this last promotion occurs even if *both* operands are of short type. You can't avoid promotion to an int with `(b + (short) 1)`.

From [15.18.2. Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)

> The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the promoted type of its operands.

Comment: It does describe this in the excerpt above, but I would emphasize here is that `short` operands are promoted to `int`, even if both are `short`s. So `short a = 32767; short b = 1; System.out.println(a + b);` would still print `32768`; this is slightly surprising, hence worth calling out explicitly.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Good catch, I worded that incorrectly. Fixed above.

Answer (score 3):

doing `+` automatically promotes `short` to `int`. Do this and you will see the overflow.

```
System.out.println("b+1: "+(short)(b+1)); //-32768
```

From the Java Language Specification, [5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>   both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>     to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is
>     converted to long.
> - Otherwise, **both operands are converted to type int**.

Notice the last rule, so essentially that means that even if they are both shorts, they will be promoted to int, this can't be avoided.

you could:

```
short b= 32767;
short d= 12;
System.out.println("b+1: "+ (d+b)); // 32779
```

And the answer would still be valid.

Answer (score 3):

No need for confusion, try this:

```
short b = 32767;
short c = b + 1;
```

What do you get? Right, you get:

> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short
>       short c = b + 1;

So, what happens at your line?
`System.out.println("b+1: "+(b+1));`?

Well, `b+1` is too big for `short`, as you said correctly, but here you add an int to it, making the result an int as well. And 32768 is a valid int.

As others already pointed out, if you explicitly cast it down to `(short)` you get what you asked for.

On the other hand that does not work for `short c = b + 1;` as here the declared type is a short, while the actual type is an `int`.

`short c = (short) (b + 1);` solves that "problem"

Comment: @andy-turner Actually I do: https://repl.it/GNMT/1 (same in Scala with a `val c: Short = Short.MaxValue + 1` -> error: type mismatch; found: Int, required: Short)

Comment: Spoke too soon :) Yes, I checked it and found it too. That surprises me; I'd have thought that the automatic narrowing check on constant values would be able to know the warning was unnecessary.

Comment: Aaah, I see. It's because the constant value definitely doesn't fit into the `short` range that you still get the warning. You don't get the warning for `final short b = 32766;`.

Answer (score 2):

`1` is an `int` literal. When you compute `b+1`, you in fact promote `b` to an `int` and then add `1`, resulting in `32768`, which is a perfectly legal `int` value. If you cast it down to a `short` again, you'll see the overflow you're expecting (`-32768`):

```
System.out.println("b+1: " + (short)(b + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, addition promotes the operands to `int`.

Note that the `+=` operator automatically does the casting back to `short`:

```
short b=32767;
System.out.println(b + 1);  // 32768, because of integer promotion.

b += 1;                     // Equivalent to b = (short)(b + 1);
System.out.println(b);      // -32768
```

`b++;`/`++b;` would yield the same result as `b += 1`.